# How to include volumes in my docker configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a docker-compose configuration for an MEAN app that's working fine.

I would like my angular (ng serve) and express servers (nodemon) to rerun automaticaly when I hit ctrl + s as if I was running my app in local.

For that, my containers need to be aware that the files changed.

How can I do that ?

Angular's Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:10

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Express's Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:6

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'

services:
  angular: # name of the first service
    build: client # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

  express: #name of the second service
    build: server # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - database

  database: # name of the third service
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Both Angular and Express have an .dockerignore for node_modules

Comment: What do you hope to gain by running this in Docker, as opposed to just running `npm start` in a standard developer environment?

Comment: I want to learn using Docker and Kubernetes. I found it was a good idea to use it during development process. Otherwise, I wouldn't feel confident to use it in prod.

Comment: Develop your application outside of Docker, and deploy it using the Dockerfile setup you've shown.  While there's a "standard" Node-in-Docker pattern you should be able to readily find, it is simultaneously less convenient than just using Node and fundamentally different from a production deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in dev environment, you can add the `volumes` section in your `docker-compose.yml` as below :

```
services:
  angular: # name of the first service
    build: client # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
   volumes:
      - /path/in/host/machine:/path/in/container

  express: #name of the second service
    build: server # specify the directory of the Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - /path/in/host/machine:/path/in/container

  database: # name of the third service
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

Reference:

[volumes in docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/)